# Javascript Closure in web applications

Tags: javascript

I have been learning about closures in javascript and I've read some articles and explanations on how they can be used. I am looking for sample web application where javascript closures are used extensively. Can anyone guide me in this?

Comment: what is your case study? post it here. just go to google and search javascript closures, then it can find you tons of examples, blogs and tutorials.

Comment: The jQuery framework relies heavily on closures, just like every modern piece of JavaScript written...

Comment: Try [Private Static Members in Javascript](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/cornford/js_info/private_static.html) or [Javascript Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). There are many other articles too. Once you learn to recognise the [javascript module pattern](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+module+pattern) you'll see it everywhere.